# Remove PDF left and right margins/whitespace when converting to .txt file using C#/Spire.PDF NuGet Package

Tags: c#

So I am trying to convert a standard A4 PDF file into a .txt file using Spire.Pdf NuGet Package, and whenever I do it there is a lot of whitespace at the start of each line where the margins of the document go I presume. I managed to solve the issue using the TrimStart() method but I want to be able to do remove the margins using Spire.Pdf itself.

I have played around with setting a PdfTextExtractOptions ExtractArea RectangleF but for some reason it cuts the bottom of the text and I lose rows.

My code is:

```
PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument();
doc.LoadFromFile(@"path");


var content = new List<string>();

RectangleF rectangle = new RectangleF(45, 0, 0, 0);

PdfTextExtractOptions options = new() { IsExtractAllText = true, IsShowHiddenText = true, ExtractArea = rectangle };

foreach (PdfPageBase page in doc.Pages)

{
    PdfTextExtractor textExtractor = new(page);

    //extract text from a specific rectangular area here - defualt A4 margin sizes?
    string extractedText = textExtractor.ExtractText(options);
    content.Add(extractedText);
}

FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"outputFile.txt", FileMode.Create);
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
string txtBefore = (string.Join("\n", content));

sw.Write(txtBefore);
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can try the code below to extract text from PDF, it will not generate extra white spaces at the start of each line in the result .txt file. I already tested it.

```
PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument();
doc.LoadFromFile(@"test.pdf");

PdfTextExtractOptions options = new PdfTextExtractOptions();
options.IsSimpleExtraction = true;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach (PdfPageBase page in doc.Pages)
{
    PdfTextExtractor extractor = new PdfTextExtractor(page);
    sb.AppendLine(extractor.ExtractText(options));
}

File.WriteAllText("Extract.txt", sb.ToString());
```